# grep a byte-point without macth-output

Tags: unix, grep

I'm using a `grep`

I want to output only offset-point.

But now my commands are being printed out to *offsets* and *macthing-keywords*.

My command is

```
grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt
```

output is..

```
15 : macthing-keywords
```

I want '15' to be printed out, representing offset (not macthing-keywords is printed)

Can you tell me how?

Comment: grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt|cut -d: -f1    can do  it too,  
and there is no option can turn off grep printing match content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply remove any `<space>:<space><anything that remains here>` with a `sed` command like `sed 's/ : .*//'` or you may delete all after first `:` with `cut -d: -f1` (as suggested by [@bigdataolddriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11940163/bigdataolddriver)):

```
grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt | sed 's/ : .*//'
```

Or

```
grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt | cut -d: -f1
```

To output to a file:

```
grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt | sed 's/ : .*//' > outputfile.txt
```

If you have multiple matches per line, you may need to separate them before running `sed` or `cut`:

```
xargs -0 | grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt | \
  xargs -0 -n1 | cut -d: -f1 > outputfile.txt
```

Or, which seems safer as it will remove `:...` even if the matches contain linebreaks and those match continuations might also have `:` in them (but this solution requires `sed` that supports `\xXX` notation):

```
xargs -0 | grep -Pbzo 'macthing-keywords' test.txt  | \
   sed 's/ *:[^\x00]*//g' | xargs -0 -n1 > outputfile.txt
```

The `xargs -0` / `xargs -0 -n1` pair will handle the match breaks turning NULs to newlines.